# html img src not loading images from imgur with flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to show an image from Imgur (for space conservation) it's not loading at all.
Works fine in a raw HTML file tho.

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/s6eSELd.png"> <br>
<!-- just an example image -->
```

log:

```
how_to_install:16 GET https://i.imgur.com/s6eSELd.png 403
app.js:11 Social Blade: Initializing on www.youtube.com
www-embed-player.js:655 GET https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/id net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
pi @ www-embed-player.js:655
mi @ www-embed-player.js:642
(anonymous) @ www-embed-player.js:1062
If @ www-embed-player.js:466
pn @ www-embed-player.js:1059
Rh @ www-embed-player.js:1074
Dn @ www-embed-player.js:1079
En @ www-embed-player.js:1080
(anonymous) @ www-embed-player.js:1333
(anonymous) @ AYIDJ2xe1nQ:7
app.js:8 Social Blade: Debugging
app.js:8 No Early Body and no YTD App  Keep checking for Material Design.
www-embed-player.js:1185 GET https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
lp @ www-embed-player.js:1185
ip @ www-embed-player.js:1182
hp @ www-embed-player.js:1181
qp @ www-embed-player.js:1190
(anonymous) @ www-embed-player.js:1338
(anonymous) @ AYIDJ2xe1nQ:7
favicon.ico:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/favicon.ico 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

(the page has a youtube video embed that's why there is so much mention of it in the log)
I have no idea why that happens.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I had to change `app.run()` to `app.run('0.0.0.0')` for some reason it doesn't work with `localhost`

Comment: Yes, you will find out that in many cases service providers limit localhosts to prevent unnecessary work load on their servers as well as preventing some security risks.